How can I hide button in customize step in step form
this is my script that manage a stepform movement:
(function ($) {
    "use strict"

    var form = $("#step-form-horizontal");
    form.children('div').steps({
        headerTag: "h4",
        bodyTag: "section",
        transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
        autoFocus: true,
        onStepChanging: function (event, currentIndex, newIndex) {
            // Check if the user is moving to the second step
            if (newIndex === 1) {
                // Scroll to the top of the page
                $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'fast');
            }
            // Validate the form on each step change
            form.validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled,:hidden";
            return form.valid();
        }
    });

    var form2 = $("#step-form-tab");
    form2.children('div').steps({
        headerTag: "h4",
        bodyTag: "section",
        enableFinishButton: false,
        enablePagination: false,
        enableAllSteps: true,
        titleTemplate: "#title#"
    });

    var form3 = $('#step-form-vertical');
    form3.children('div').steps({
        headerTag: "h4",
        bodyTag: "section",
        transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
        stepsOrientation: "vertical"
    });

})(jQuery);

But I want to delete next/previous button in just form3 in this part of my view:

    <h4>Payment</h4>
      <section id="#payment">
     <div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="basic-form">
  <form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="SaveDeliveryAndPaymentDetails" method="post">

     <div class="form-group">.....


                                                                        </form>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </section>

and this is the id of may main form: I want to show next/previous in form1 and form2 but does not show in form 3
#step-form-horizontal
and this is for buttons:
<div class="calendar " id="calendar">
    <div class="header">
        <button id="prevBtn">&lt;</button>
        <h2 id="monthYear">Month Year</h2>
        <button id="nextBtn">&gt;</button>
    </div>
    <div class="days" id="daysContainer"></div>
</div>


Welcome to Stack Overflow. This seems to be using a Plugin. Please provide a [mcve].
